# Looping audio on separate thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, audio

I am making a 2d RPG game and i was wanting to get background music working. I wrote a sound class that plays the music on a separate thread but i cannot figure out how to make it loop. My Sound class is as follows:

```
package tileRPG.gfx;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;


public class Sound implements Runnable 
{

    private String fileLocation = "res/bgMusic.wav";

    public Sound() { }

    public void play() 
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        playSound(fileLocation);
    }

    private void playSound(String fileName) 
    {
        File soundFile = new File(fileName);
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
        try 
        {
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AudioFormat audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        SourceDataLine line = null;
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        try 
        {
            line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(audioFormat);
        } 
        catch (LineUnavailableException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        line.start();
        int nBytesRead = 0;
        byte[] abData = new byte[128000];
        while (nBytesRead != -1) 
        {
            try 
            {
                nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (nBytesRead >= 0) 
            {
                int nBytesWritten = line.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
            }
        }
        line.drain();
        line.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to play it again? Please confirm.

Comment: I want it to keep replaying until the program finishes

Comment: @gnomed, I wanted to fix indentation, because it wasn't good readability. Yes if author disagree with it, he can decline or undo it.

Comment: the question of where curly braces go for readability is a long running debate in software development and i don't think this website is an appropriate place to go around telling people to use one style over another (which is all the edit was doing). Readability is a subjective opinion and in contrast I find the original curly brace positioning to be more readable (as did the OP presumably).

Comment: OK, @gnomed, I agree that this is  long running debate, and I will not be fixed it, if the reason would be only this. I would not be fixed it, if the code was be like this. There were also non correct indentation, braces outside code area (take a look to original) and the goal was to fix it. But the author can undo it if he disagree with it. No problem.

Comment: @RyanHosford I see you're using a `SourceDataLine` rather than a `Clip`; are you concerned about the size of your audio file fitting in to memory? If not, is there another reason that requires you to use  `SourceDataLine`?

Comment: very useful example of implementing sound. Thank you

Comment: Hi, wonderful example of using sound! Impressed! Although I have a question. Is there any call for a method that can be used to stop the sound at a button press? Im trying this in my own school project :) Happy for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void run ()
{
    while(true)
    {
        playSound(fileLocation);
    }
}
```

This creates an infinite loop. Adjust accordingly.

When you start a thread, it will execute any code that is in the `run()` method and then exit. So this is where the loop would go in order to repeatedly play the sound (without blocking your other threads/code).

This solution has no way of stopping this thread (and therefore stopping playback) with your current code, but I assume you are writing this in stages. The thread will stop playback and exit when the application does currently.

Comment: simple and works. Thank you for the solution! I can't believe i didn't think of it by myself

Answer (score 0):

> Use recursion

Sample code:

```
private void playSound(String fileName) 
{
   ...
   line.drain();
   line.close();

   //recursive call to same method
   playSound(fileName);
}
```

---

You can make it more better by moving static part of the method `playSound()` in `run()` method. In that case you don't need to read the file again.

Hint: pass `SourceDataLine` in `playSound()` method instead of `fileName`.

Comment: This will block their code during playback (and therefore forever), which I don't think is desirable.

Comment: I assume he is using threads for a reason other than "fun". There isn't even a main method in the post, so I would not assume their program is doing nothing else (they said it is a 2D game)

Comment: @gnomed I have updated it in my post. Please confirm.

Comment: or he could look at my solution which does the job with a single additional line. I dont think a thread dedicated to nothing but running another thread is very good design (which is what this code is doing).

Comment: lol that works but it has 2 flaws. First, it is not the most readable. Looking at the `run()` method you cannot tell that it will never return (without just already knowing the method is recursive). More importantly though is it will infinitely add to the call stack which has a finite amount of memory and will eventually crash the whole app (with a StackOverFlow Exception of all things!!)

Comment: PS: sorry, i dont like to cramp on anyones style. just pointing out what I see (and you are welcome to say I am wrong and do your own thing).